# How should I manage an intermediary vector after moving/swapping it in the constructor?

Tags: c++, new-operator, raw-pointer

I am learning about memory management and not quite sure how how to manage the delete and/or destructor policy.

Suppose I have the following template:

```
template <typename X>
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;
  size_t dbSize;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) {
    dbSize = n;
    <vector<vector<X>> *tmp = new vector<vector<X>>(dbSize);
    db = std::move(*tmp);
    // db = std::swap(tmp);
    delete tmp;
  }

  ~DBContainer() { /* how should I delete `db`? */ }
  // ~DBContainer() = default;
};
```

How should I set the destructor policy for `db`? I understand that for a raw pointer, `std::move` only copies the intermediary vector of vectors to `db`; therefore, I still need to delete the intermediary dynamically allocated vector. I could be wrong but I believe it is the same for `std::swap`.

But then, at the end of the program, how should I manage the destructor policy for `db`? Do I simply set it to default?

Comment: Heads up, I edited out your `unique_ptr` question since posts shouldn't contain multiple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you construct dynamically with `new` needs to be `delete`'d when you are done using it.  `std::unique_ptr` can help with that by calling `delete` for you when it is itself destructed, eg:

```cpp
template <typename X>
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;
  size_t dbSize;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) {
    dbSize = n;
    std::unique_ptr<vector<vector<X>>> tmp(new vector<vector<X>>(dbSize));
    // or: auto tmp = std::make_shared<vector<vector<X>>>(dbSize);
    db = std::move(*tmp);
  } // <-- tmp is destroyed here, delete'ing the temp vector

  //~DBContainer() = default;
};
```

It doesn't matter that the *content* of `tmp` is moved to `db`, `tmp` itself still needs to be `delete`'d.

However, since `db` is not being dynamically constructed via `new`, there is no need to `delete` it.  It will be destructed automatically when its owning `DBContainer` object is destructed.  Only your temporary `vector` that is being constructed via `new` needs to be `delete`'d.  But even that can be avoided, by simply not constructing the temporary `vector` dynamically at all, eg:

```cpp
template <typename X>
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;
  size_t dbSize;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) {
    dbSize = n;
    vector<vector<X>> tmp(dbSize);
    db = std::move(tmp);
  } // <-- tmp is destroyed here

  //~DBContainer() = default;
};
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
template <typename X>
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;
  size_t dbSize;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) {
    dbSize = n;
    db = vector<vector<X>>(dbSize); // <-- temp destroyed after operator= exits
  }

  //~DBContainer() = default;
};
```

That being said, you don't actually need the temporary `vector` at all.  You can (and should) initialize `db` directly, in the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), eg:

```cpp
template <typename X>
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;
  size_t dbSize;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) : db(n), dbSize(n) { }

  //~DBContainer() = default;
};
```

And technically, you can get rid of `dbSize` too, just use `db.size()` whenever needed:

```cpp
class DBContainer {
private:
  vector<vector<X>> db;

public:
  DBContainer(size_t n = 100) : db(n) { }

  //~DBContainer() = default;
};
```